Given a ring $R$ and a maximal ideal $I$, must the set $\{J \subsetneq I\}$ have the property that every element is contained in a maximal element?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I \subsetneq R$ an ideal that is maximal among the proper subideals of $R$. Let $K \subsetneq I$ be an ideal. Must it necessarily be true that there exists an ideal $J$ with $K \subseteq J \subsetneq I$ which is maximal among the proper subideals of $I$?
For example, this is true if $I$ is finitely generated: Assume that $I = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \rangle$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a chain of ideals such that for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, we have $K \subseteq A \subsetneq I$. Let $B = \bigcup \mathcal{A}$. Then $B$ is an ideal with $K \subseteq B$. We also have $B \subseteq I$. Striving for a contradiction, assume that $B = I$. Now, for each $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have $x_k \in B$, so there must exist $A_k \in \mathcal{A}$ with $x_k \in A_k$. Because $\mathcal{A}$ is totally ordered with respect to inclusion, we can let $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \in \mathcal{A}$. But now $A$ is an ideal with $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in A$, so we have $I = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \rangle \subseteq A$. But this would imply $A = I$, a contradiction. Hence we must have $B \subsetneq I$ and therefore $K \subseteq B \subsetneq I$. Therefore, every chain $\mathcal{A}$ of ideals $A$ with $K \subseteq A \subsetneq I$ has an upper bound $B$ with $K \subseteq B \subsetneq I$, and hence by Zorn's Lemma, we have a maximal ideal $J$ with $K \subseteq J \subsetneq I$.

Perhaps this: take the ring of algebraic integers. Localize away from the ideal $(2^{1/n}\mid n\geq 1)$ so it is maximal.  I don't think it has any ideals maximal among properly contained in that ideal.

By passing to the quotient ring $R/K$ we see it suffices to solve the problem when $K=0$, so we seek a maximal subideal of $0 \neq I' = I/K$. Viewed as an $R$-module, your proof has rediscovered that finitely generated modules contain maximal submodules (although note that you require $I \neq 0$).
Here is a counterexample. Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, \dots]/(x_1^2, x_2^2 - x_1, x_3^2 - x_2,  \dots)$ with maximal ideal $I = (x_1, x_2, \dots)$. Suppose $J$ is a maximal subideal.
Note if $x_n \in J$ then $x_{n-1}, \dots, x_1 \in J$. Take the smallest $n$ such that $x_n \not\in J$. So $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1} \in J$ and $x_n \not\in J$ and so $I = J + (x_n)$. So $x_{n+1} = j + rx_n$ and hence $x_{n+1} - rx_n \in J$. By difference of two squares, $x_n - r^2 x_{n-1} = x_{n+1}^2 - r^2 x_n^2 = (x_{n+1} - r x_n)(x_{n+1} + r x_n) \in J$ and as $x_{n-1} \in J$ we get $x_n \in J$, a contradiction.

What do you mean by "by difference of two squares"?

@Smiley1000 $(x_2 - rx_1)(x_2 + rx_1)$ is a multiple of $x_2 - rx_1$

But why is $x_1 = x_2^2 - r^2 x_1^2$?

@Smiley1000 $R$ has the relation $x_1^2 = 0$ and $x_2^2 = x_1$

Thank you very much for the example! One more question, could you be a bit more formal about "wlog $n = 1$ by quotienting out $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1} \rangle$? I don't think that part is clear to me yet.

One should observe that we can also view this ring as $\mathbb{Q}[x, \sqrt[2]{x}, \sqrt[4]{x}, \sqrt[8]{x}, \ldots]/\langle x^2 \rangle$.

@Smiley1000 By the correspondence theorem, the ideals of $R/(x_1, ..., x_{n-1})$ are in order-preserving bijection with the ideals or $R$ containing $(x_1, ..., x_{n-1})$. So as $J$ is the maximal subideal of $I$ and contains these $n-1$ terms, we can go to this quotient and retain the maximality.
However this is not integral to the argument. The only change you'd have to make if you left it as $n$ is that the final equation becomes $x_n - r^2 x_{n-1} = x_{n+1}^2 - r^2 x_{n}^2 \in J$ and $x_{n-1} \in J$ by assumption so $x_n \in J$, the same contradiction.

In order to give a negative answer to this question, it is sufficient to give an example of a maximal ideal $m$ of a ring $R$ such that no ideal is maximal among the ideals properly contained in $m$. One way to construct such rings uses the theory of valuation rings. In case anyone reading this is unfamiliar with this theory, I'll sketch the relevant definitions and facts.
A surjective group homomorphism $v:K^{*}\rightarrow \Gamma$, where $K$ is a field and $\Gamma$ is a totally ordered abelian group, is said to be a valuation if $$v(x+y) \geq min(v(x),v(y))$$ for $x,y \in K^{*}$. Then $$R:=\{x \in K^{*} : v(x) \geq 0 \} \cup \{0\}$$ is a subring of $K$. Such rings are called valuation rings, and $\Gamma$ is called the value group of $R$. (Value groups are unique).
A nonempty subset $S \subseteq \Gamma$ is called a positive segment if $0 \leq s$ for any $s \in S$ and whenever $0 \leq t \leq s$ with $s \in S$, we have $t \in S$. There is an inclusion-reversing bijection $\Phi$ between the proper ideals of $R$ and the positive segments of $\Gamma$, given by $$\Phi(I)=v(R \setminus I).$$ Since $0$ is the unique minimal positive segment of $S$, we see that $R$ is local with maximal ideal $\Phi^{-1}(0)$.
We have the following nontrivial fact: for any totally ordered abelian group $\Gamma$, there exists a valuation $v$ with codomain $\Gamma$.
We are now in a position to give the example. We may take $\Gamma = (\mathbb{R},+)$, and let $R$ be a corresponding valuation ring. Let $S$ be any positive segment of $\mathbb{R}$ properly containing $0$, and let $s \in S \setminus 0$. Then $[0,s)$ is a positive segment properly contained in $S$. So there is no minimal positive segment properly containing $0$. Applying the correspondence $\Phi$, we see that there is no ideal maximal with respect to being properly contained in $\Phi^{-1}(0)=m$, which is the unique maximal ideal of $R$.
Edit:
For references on the theory of valuation rings, I personally learned the topic from Introduction to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah and MacDonald, in particular chapter 5 and exercises 30-33. I also think chapter 17 of Pete L Clark's notes is a good presentation. For some other suggestions, see this thread on the topic.

That's a really natural example. Could you add a reference?

I've added some references. If this wasn't quite what you're looking for, let me know.
